# Commands in custom shortcuts

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

When I went from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I lost the ability to do screen shots the way I'm used to.  I want a keyboard combo that lets me select a section of screen and have it saved as a file.  So I created a custom shortcut.  But since it's a screen shot, I want each file to have a unique name.  From the terminal, I can

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f Pictures/Screenshots/"Screenshot from $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").png"
```

However, if I do that in the custom shortcut, the 'date' command is never executed.

How do I wind up with a file name that's unique>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell expansions and variable expansions do not work when launching a command from a hotkey. Instead run your command as follows, i.e., explicitly starting a shell to run it in:

```
sh -c 'gnome-screenshot -a -f Pictures/Screenshots/"Screenshot from $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").png'
```